# Not getting details of people checked in via the foursquare herenow api call

Tags: android, geolocation, foursquare

Before making the foursquare herenow API call I first checkin to that venue and I even pass the lat/lang parameters but for some reason I only get the count of ppl and not their details.

What could the possible cause for the issue be?
I`m trying this in India...could this issue be country specific?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your check-in has been tagged as an illegitimate check-in. This can be caused by making many check-ins in a short period of time, which is common when testing check-ins in development. Try waiting a few minutes before checking in again.

Comment: Thanks for the response....i tried your suggestion but the issue persists......I suspect that I am being marked as a cheat though for some other reason.....one reason could be that i`m checking in to a location but i`m not close enough for the herenow API to return ppl info....i have gone very close to couple of locations and checked in but I still see the error.....maybe the herenow requirements are too  stringent..... wondering how I can bypass this.....

Comment: On a related note I think FS should have a developer mode where its easier to test out stuff and not be hindered by the anti cheating rules.

Comment: Yes, if you are checking into locations very far away from your actual location, those will also be tagged as cheats. If you are checking in as a normal user would (that is, to locations that you are actually present at, and not too frequently), you should not urn into any cheating issues.